# How to deal with extra pins on reversible connectors?

Tags: reverse-polarity

I want a header on my board to be reversible. The header has 4 UARTs, 4 power pins (VA,VB,VC,VD), and power (3V3) and PWM for a servo. The functions of most of the signal pins of the header are symmetric, so channels A,B,C,D become D,C,B,A if the polarity is reversed. The only exception is a PWM connection. I'm wondering if having two pins for the PWM signal is going to cause issues. Should I connect these two pins together on both ends or only one end? Or is there a better way to deal with it? The pinout is pictured below.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be no issue with tying the pins together on both ends. Have you considered making your connector an 18 pin connector? This leaves you with no extra pins, and you can make everything symmetric.

What frequency is your PWM?